# Adding conditions in MERGE statement in Oracle SQL for INSERT/UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to insert/update some RECORDS in table target_table. These records are coming one source_table.

I am using MERGE for update/insert the target_table.

```
MERGE
   INTO  target_table tgt
   USING source_table src
   ON  ( src.column1 = tgt.column1 and
         src.column2 = tgt.column2)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE
   SET   tgt.column3= src.column3,
         tgt.column4 = src.coulmn4   
WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
INSERT ( tgt.column1,
         tgt.column2,
         tgt.column3,
         tgt.column4 )
VALUES ( src.coulmn1,
         src.coulmn2,
         src.coulmn3,
         src.coulmn4);
```

I want to add some specific condition on update.

`IF target_table.column3 in (val1','val2)`

then only there should be update, else no update or insert.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can simply add `WHERE` clause to `UPDATE`. [More about it in oracle docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#i2081030)

So in your case it should look like:

```
...
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE
   SET   tgt.column3= src.column3,
         tgt.column4 = src.coulmn4
   WHERE tgt.column3 IN (val1, val2) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
...
```

Comment: Hi Psur, I have a similar problem, but I have 2 conditions in where condition in Update clause. But only one of them works. If I use both the conditions it updates 0 records, otherwise it updates ~700K or ~80K records. With both the conditions I am expecting only ~60 records to be updated. Any pointers would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: What to do if i have a separate condtion per each updating column?

Answer (score 1):

Instead Try Doing As below:

```
MERGE
INTO  target_table tgt
USING source_table src
ON  (src.column1 = tgt.column1)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
UPDATE
SET   tgt.column3= src.column3,
     tgt.column4 = src.coulmn4  
WHERE src.column1 = tgt.column1 and
     src.column2 = tgt.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
INSERT ( tgt.column1,
     tgt.column2,
     tgt.column3,
     tgt.column4 )
VALUES ( src.coulmn1,
     src.coulmn2,
     src.coulmn3,
     src.coulmn4);
```